# I got this error when i try to update the joomla version to 2.5 from 1.5.24 by using jupgrade

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I have found a way to update the joomla version from 1.5 to 2.5 using jupgrade.

I have downloaded the jupgradePro , but it throws an error when I uploaded it in the Extension manager in the administrator  .

```
**JFolder::create: Could not create directory
Warning! Failed to move file.**
```

Comment: You are looking for http://www.joomla.org/ it also has a support section.

Comment: This is not a matter of the method you're using, it's a matter of file and folder permissions. Ensure that folder are 755 and files are 644. To do this, in your Joomla admin panel go to **Help** >> **System Info** >> **Directory Permissions**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla has documentation on migrating from 1.5  to 2.5:

http://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_from_Joomla_1.5_to_Joomla_2.5

Comment: Hi Pekka , Thanks for the info , i see it already in that they are using a premium plugin (Jupgrade) .  Any other ideas .

Comment: @user premium? Not sure what you mean. It looks free and Open-source.

Comment: JUpgrade is not premium..... do your research http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/11658

Comment: yes thanks , i downloaded the jupgrade ,let me try it

Answer (score 0):

my opinion is to create a fresh joomla 2.5 site.

i try to update my joomla site from 1.5 to 2.5 and a lot of errors came up. a specially with old old components that are not support joomla 2.5